# How to count number of <tr> rows in HTML table from BASH script

Tags: html, bash, perl, awk

I have html file with a table containing rows with 3 different ids like  and 
My requirement is i need to get the count of each type of the rows using BASH script.

Sorry for not providing sample i/p:

```
<table border="1">
<tr id='Type1'>
<td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id='Type2'>
<td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id='Type1'>
<td>Row 3, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 3, Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id='Type2'>
<td>Row 4, Column 1</td>
<td>Row 4, Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Expected o/p from shell is : Type1 rows =2, Type 2 rows= 2

Comment: Edit your question to show sample input and expected output. The statement `i need to get the count of each type of the rows` in particular is highly ambiguous.

Comment: `perl -0777 -E 'say $n =()= <> =~ / <\s*tr /xgi' file` won't post as an answer as one-liners are often despised. `:o`

Comment: Nice use of the `=()=` Saturn operator on the `<>` diamond operator

Answer (score 4):

If your real data is always formatted exactly like your sample input then:

```
$ awk -F"'" '/<tr/{cnt[$2]++} END{for (type in cnt) print type, "rows =", cnt[type]}' file
Type1 rows = 2
Type2 rows = 2
```

Per @choroba's request: Some things that could go wrong = the whole table on one line, a part of the table commented out, the tr having attributes (`<tr style="...">`), etc.

Comment: Maybe you can mention things that could go wrong: the whole table on one line, a part of the table commented out, etc.

Comment: @Ed Morton, thanks for the answer!! thats almost same as my req but i have 2 different tr tags diffrentiated by ID where i want the count of two tr tags separately

Answer (score 2):

Using a plain bash script for this would be more complex than necessary. I would suggest Perl. If we assume that all of your input files are more or less similar to the example, the following should work:

```
# If all the HTML documents in your set are in the same format as your sample
perl -lne '$rows{$_}++ for '"/<tr id='([^']*)'/g"';  END { print "$_ rows=$rows{$_}" for keys %rows; }' filename
```

Here's what it does:

1. For all text matching *<tr id='some_id'*, it increments the count associated with *some_id*
2. In the end, it iterates over all the IDs that were found and prints them with their associated counts

The regex is pretty restrictive, so it won't work if there are multiple spaces before the ID or if the ID is in double quotes or in many other cases that are possible with HTML markup. So you might need to customise the regex. In some cases, modifying the regex also would not be sufficient - for example if if the *<tr* and the *id=* are on different lines. In complex scenarios, using a HTML parser would be best.

Comment: @vrk :I believe you can slurp the file and then count the number of <tr which will be easy way in perl. Note : Do when file size is less

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk '/<tr / {a[$0]++} END{for(i in a) print i, a[i]}' xml
```

gives

```
<tr id='Type2'> 2
<tr id='Type1'> 2
```